# Combine multiple schemas in fluent-json-schema

Tags: jsonschema, fastify

I'm defining some routing schemes for fastify.
I would like to reuse the code of some schema by combining them together without making redundancy.
How can I combine two patterns into one?

```js
const Dataset = S.object()
      .prop('dataset',
        S.string().enum(datasetsNames)
      )
      .default('default')
      .required();

const Locations = S.object()
      .prop('locations', S.string())

const CombinedParams = S.object()//...COMBINE Locations and Dataset...???

const schemas = {

  schemaDatasetParams: {
    description: 'schema having only Dataset',
    query: ...,
    params: Dataset,
  },

  schemaDatasetLocationsParams: {
    description: 'schema having a comination of Locations and Dataset',
    query: ...,
    params: CombinedParams
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const schema1 = S.object()
    .additionalProperties(false)
    .prop('name', S.string().minLength(2))
    .prop('email', S.string().format(S.FORMATS.EMAIL))
    .prop('password', S.string().minLength(6))
    .prop('userRoles', S.array().items(S.number()).minItems(1));

const schema2 = S.object().prop('id', S.number()).required();

const combinedSchema = schema1.without(['password']).extend(schema2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine schemas with `allOf` but you need to be careful with certain properties when they are combined. using `additionalProperties:false` in any of your schemas could become a problem for validation if you don't structure the root schema correctly.

I don't see any common properties in your schemas to refactor into a component schema, but if you want to combine these two schemas into one, this should work.

```js
const CombinedParams = S.allOf([Dataset,Locations])
```

*src: https://github.com/fastify/fluent-json-schema/blob/master/docs/API.md#allOf*